# Problem in html to java class parsing using XMLC

Tags: java, html, parsing

i have compiled HTML page using XMLC jar file command..

```
java org.enhydra.xml.xmlc.commands.xmlc.XMLC -d \core\model\template -class core.model.template.patientPrescriptionsHTML \\core\\model\\template\\PrePrintPrescription.html
```

it propogate error like

```
patientPrescriptionsHTML.java:17: core.model.template.patientPrescript
ionsHTML is not abstract and does not override abstract method renameNode(org.w3
c.dom.Node,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) in org.w3c.dom.Document
public class patientPrescriptionsHTML extends org.enhydra.xml.xmlc.html.HTMLObje
ctImpl implements org.enhydra.xml.xmlc.XMLObject, org.enhydra.xml.xmlc.html.HTML
Object {
       ^
1 error
Error: compile of generated java code failed
```

please suggest...

Answer (score 0):

In

```
class A extends B implements C {
}
```

A must implement all abstract methods from B and C (because C is an interface, all of C's methods count implicitly as abstract.)
Unless, of course, A itself is abstract.